# Hadoop Job fails when using PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

I am trying to run basic pig script on cluster not able to submit job it gets fail with the following warning message:

### WARN

> org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher
>   
> - Ooops! Some job has failed! Specify -stop_on_failure if you want
>   Pig to stop immediately on failure.

Not able to read file in the cluster using PIG even when specifying correct location can anyone help me on this?

### ERROR

```
Failed to read data from "hdfs://172.16.30.119:8020/user/hadoop/wordfile"
```

### CODE

```
data = load 'hdfs://172.16.30.119:8020/user/hadoop/wordfile';
```

Comment: can you pls share command output: `yarn logs -applicationId application_1501154558527_0003`

Comment: hey thanks squid! i found it by myself after few hours....problem is when file is in single block pig easily find and runs the job The file which i am trying to execute is a single file but stored in 10blocks where pig is not reading that file.....can you help me on this